# Hazelcast : server node and client node best practices for beginner

Tags: hazelcast

*new to hazelcast*, want to understand functionalities of client and server functions in a cluster.
lets say I have 4 different servers(not referring to hazelcast server)/machines and I want to maximize RAM utilization  :-

- Do I start 4 servers instances, one on each server/machine ?
- Do I start 4 clients instances, one on each server/machine ?
- Is business logic written only in client instance ? if so, then do server instance not contain any logic apart from managing the lifecycle ?

I know this would vary as per requirement, but I want to get a general idea.

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors: how much memory each node has, how you want to partition or replicate the data, how much you want data to be "local" to your applications, etc. As you said, this is probably something you want to work out based on your requirements. There's no general rule. You just need to know that client nodes don't participate in holding data or running tasks.

Comment: "client nodes don't participate in holding data or running tasks" could you elaborate this ?

Comment: do client only contain business logic ? and server just the life cycle logic?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.3/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-topology. Clients can be normal applications. They're only "client" as far as the hazelcast cluster is concerned.

Comment: exactly what i was searching for.. thanks.
https://hazelcast.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004441586-What-s-the-difference-between-client-server-vs-embedded-topologies-

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Ernest's statements. You would usually expect data to be held in cache and processing to be on the client. However, with hazelcast, it doesn't have to be that way. Check some interesting features like ExecutorService and EntryProcessors in the documentation.

You may also want to look at the concept of Near cache, where you still hold the data on dedicated Hz instance (servers), while maintaining a near-cache in the client. Be wary of data sync challenges around this, though this works well in most cases (again very subjective).
Hope these pointers give some idea to start off with. All the Best !

Answer (score 0):

there is no single answer to your question. There are many factors to be considered. For example one of your questions is where does the business logic reside. This depends heavily on how the hazelcast is used. Lets say Hazelcast is used purly for Caching purposes. The business logic then resides entirly on the client side.

Alternativly if we say that Hazelcast is full of rich Pojos, and domain driven design is used then we can say the logic lies entirly on the hazelcast instance itself. Usualy in real life the truth is somewhere on between

In terms of memory utilization again this depends very much on your setup budget and so on....  We can say that if you have one server with a lot of ram and you don't use any commersial addons from Hazelcast like off memory heap then running several hazelcasts on the same machine with limited amount of memory each would be more beneficial compared to running a single node with a lot of memory.

Also it should be noted the phenomenon where allocating more than 32Gigs of heap will drive you into te 64 bit universe.

Again this depends on many factors. If you have a Live interactive application you can not tolerate big GC pausas so you would incline to usage of more hazelcasts with small heaps. If you have non interactive application tolerant to big GC pauses then it is the other way around you can have big heap. So you see there is no simple answer to your question.